# Unable to change brightness with ubuntu 13.10 on ASUS 453t series (It worked with Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: brightness, system-settings

The brightness icon is shown but nothing happens.
Even if I try to change the brightness in "System Settings" nothing happens.
The thing is it didn't happen with Ubuntu 13.04, so I would like to know how to solve it or how to erase the upgrade to use the 13.04 version.

Answer (score 2):

Got the workaround for this

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub`. Change the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and then save and then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then restart the computer, then it should work.

This might allow you to reduce the brightness from 'Brightness & Lock' in system settings. But your function combination keys might not work. Though this is not a perfect solution, you can get the job done with this :-)

Comment: thanks for this solution, but it doesn't work for me. As a matter of fact, the brightness settings disappear entirely from the system settings if I do this --- slider is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of worked for me. The hotkeys sort of work sometimes, I have at least dimmed the display from where it was.

The settings slider don't work at all!

The catalyst control for brightness works.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try would be to create the file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf with the following content:

> Section "Device"
>
> ```
>     Identifier  "card0"
>     Driver      "intel"
>     Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
>     BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
> ```
>
> EndSection

...and log out and back in again to see if it works. Try it without any additional kernel parameters.